# Debugging node.js running in IIS

Tags: debugging, node.js, webstorm, iisnode

Has anyone managed to get debug Node.js with IISNode using Webstorm 5.x? I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: Can you be specific as to what the issue is, and your configuration?

Comment: IIS 7.5, IISNode, Node.js 64 bit. Local debug works ok outside of IIS, but not remote with IIS, doesn't hit breakpoints or connect.